# use of 'ir.attachment' in binary field-- odoo

Tags: python, attachment, odoo, odoo-10

what is the use of 'ir.attachment' in Binary filed of ODOO 10? How does it differ if it is not used ?

```
attachments1 = fields.Binary('Attachments')
attachments2 = fields.Binary('ir.attachment', string = 'Attachments')
```